# Bash - Print all rows with a specific column using loops

Tags: bash, awk

I've stucked on this problem for few hours, so I decided to ask to this community.

I have a log file like this:

```
gzz kre 1
mnt ttt 1
ddr ppp 2
ret typ 2
epo sst 1
plt ewr 3
```

I want to divide this file in three different files, each one having the same value in the third column.

I am able to do this statically, using awk:

```
awk '$3 == 1'  dataTX.txt > dataTX_2_$i.txt
```

Nevertheless, I can't do this using a loop. I'm trying with this:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
    awk '$3 == $i'  dataTX.txt > dataTX_2_$i.txt

done
```

But nothing appears in the three output files.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better answer, see @anubhava's.

#### Approach

Your approach (and my original answer, below) have several problems:

- Reading the input file several times instead of once
- Hardcoding of the values instead of picking up dynamically from the input

@anubhava's solution takes care of these, by redirecting the output inside a single `awk` process, making a single pass over the input, and dynamically picking up the values to use for the output filenames. As an added bonus, there are no more conditions necessary.

#### Original answer, band-aiding the wrong approach

You need to use double-quotes to embed a shell variable, and then in that case escape the `\$` in `$3`, like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
    awk "\$3 == $i"  dataTX.txt > dataTX_2_$i.txt    
done
```

Btw, avoid `seq` if possible. This will do the job just as well, and more portable:

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    awk "\$3 == $i"  dataTX.txt > dataTX_2_$i.txt    
done
```

Instead of messing with the quoting, another option is to inject a value into an Awk variable with the `-v` flag:

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    awk -v i=$i '$3 == i'  dataTX.txt > dataTX_2_$i.txt    
done
```

Comment: Don't do any of those they're all the wrong approach. See @anubhava's answer for [almost] the right solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can all that in single awk:

```
awk '{print > ("dataTX_2_" $3 ".txt")}' dataTX.txt
```

Comment: THAT is the right approach but you should put brackets around the concatenation on the right side of the `>` as as-written it's undefined behavior per POSIX.